# SpHow to merge two fields(string type) of a DataFrame's column to generate a Date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame which simplified schema has got two columns with 3 fields each column:

```
root
 |-- npaDetails: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- additionalInformation: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaStatus: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaDetails: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- npaHeaderData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaDownloadDate: string (nullable = true)     
 |    |-- npaDownloadTime: string (nullable = true)
```

Possible values:

```
npaDownloadDate - "30JAN17"
npaDownloadTime - "19.50.00"
```

I need to compare two rows in a DataFrame with this schema, to determine which one is "fresher". To do so I need to merge the fields `npaDownloadDate` and `npaDownloadTime` to generate a Date that I can compare easily.

Below its the code I have written so far. It works, but I think it takes more steps than necessary and I'm sure that Scala offers better solutions than my approach.

```
val parquetFileDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("MyParquet.parquet")

val relevantRows = parquetFileDF.filter($"npaHeaderData.npaNumber" === "123456")

val date = relevantRows .select($"npaHeaderData.npaDownloadDate").head().get(0)
val time = relevantRows .select($"npaHeaderData.npaDownloadTime").head().get(0)

val dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyykk.mm.ss").(date+time)

//I would replicate the previous steps to get dateTime2
if(dateTime.before(dateTime2))
  println("dateTime is before dateTime2")
```

So the output of `"30JAN17"` and `"19.50.00"` would be  `Mon Jan 30 19:50:00 GST 2017`

Is there another way to generate a Date from two fields of a column, without extracting and merging them as strings? Or even better, is it possible to compare directly both values (date and time) between two different rows in a dataframe to know which one has an older date

Answer (score 2):

In spark 2.2,

```
df.filter(
  to_date(
    concat(
      $"npaHeaderData.npaDownloadDate",
      $"npaHeaderData.npaDownloadTime"),
    fmt = "[your format here]")
  ) < lit(some date))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("some_name", date_format(unix_timestamp(
  concat($"npaHeaderData.npaDownloadDate", $"npaHeaderData.npaDownloadTime"),
 "ddMMMyykk.mm.ss").cast("timestamp"),
 "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy"))
```

Comment: This will output already a date with a format Mon Jan 30 19:50:00 GST 2017?